# JSON API delete 'has and belongs to many' relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, json-api, jsonapi-resources

I'm building an API for a cart-like thing with the jsonapi-resources gem, and I need an endpoint to remove an item from the cart.

Currently, I'm assuming that a client consuming this API won't need the actual 'cart items'. Instead it just needs a list of the products that are in the cart.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to delete something in jsonapi-resources  without knowing that thing's ID. I.e. there's no way for a client to remove something from the cart without it knowing the id of the join model.

Basically I need an endpoint that does something like:

`DELETE http://example.com/carts/1/cart-items?filter[product]=1`

Instead, the only option I can find is

`DELETE http://example.com/cart-items/1`

Alternatively, I could implement a custom action to handle this, but I've gone through the docs and I can't find a prescribed way of writing custom actions.

Comment: You mean you want to create this route `DELETE http://example.com/carts/1/cart-items?filter[product]=1`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I eventually worked it out. That was just an example of what the route *could* look like if the gem provided such functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for hours, in the process of writing this question I finally worked out the answer. It's not at all well documented, though — I had to read through the gem's tests to work it out.

`curl -X DELETE -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" \
--data '{ "data" : [{"type": "products", "id": 185 }]  }' \ http://localhost:3000/api/v1/carts/4085/relationships/products`

This successfully deleted the item from the cart (and did not touch the product record itself).